# C++ Calculating an average of a variable width of numbers in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, average

I am aware that there allready are similar questions here but no answer really helped me.
This is my problem:
I have given an array with 512x512 pixels in it. Each pixel has a value like 165.88009.
 ( I have to create a heatmap in GnuPlot later)

Now I want to "smoothen" it by creating the average of a variable block of pixels (like 4-16) and write it into a new 2D array and jump to the next block until it is done.
The size of the array should stay the same. So if I average 4 pixels those 4 pixels get the new value.
I made a function for this but it doesn't work properly.

Calculating the average is not my problem. The problem is that I want to have a **variable** width of pixels but I don't know how to make my algorithm jump to the next block.
Im not experienced in C++ and maybe I have to do it completely different.
So any help or inspiration is greatly appreciated :)

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <fstream>        
#include <string>         
#include <iomanip>        
using namespace std; 

int i, j, m, n, k;      

void Average(double **Data, int width)  // width gets defined and initiated in main       
{
    double sum;     
    double avg;
    fstream Output;

    Output.open( "GemittelteWerte.dat", ios::out);


    double** IV_Matrix = new double* [m];  
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        IV_Matrix[i] = new double [n];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            IV_Matrix[i][j] = 1.0;       
        }
    }

    // Here start all my troubles:
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)                 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j+=width)  
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            k=j;

            for( k; k<(j+width); k++)
            {
                sum+=Data[i][k];    
            }
            avg=(sum/width);               

            for (int k; k<(j+width); k++)
            {
                IV_Matrix[i][k] = avg;              
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) 
        {
            Output<<setprecision(10)<<IV_Matrix[i][j]<<"\t"; 
        }
        Output<<"\n";
    }

    Output.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this block a 2D block (4 = 2x2, 16 = 4x4)? You simply want to do a 2D convolution? Then better use odd widths with 3x3, 5x5, ... kernels.

```
// int x, y are the dimensions of your image

double get (double **img, int i, int j) // zero padding for areas outside image
{
    if (i<0 || i>=x || j<0 || j>=y)
        return 0;
    else
        return img[i][j];
}

void conv (double **img, double **result, int width2) // kernel is (2*width2+1)^2
{
    double sum;

    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int ii=-width2; ii<=width2; ii++)
                for (int jj=-width2; jj<=width2; jj++)
                    sum += get(img,i+ii,j+jj) / ((2*width2+1)*(2*width2+1));
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
}
```

This smoothes img to result. Its however the slow unseparated solution. For small images and kernels no problem.

**Edit**: then easier:

```
// x, y are the dimensions of your image (x rows, y colums)

void avg (double **img, double **result, int width) // width must be >= 1 and
{                                                   // should be a divider of y
    double sum;

    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) // process all rows
        {
            for (int j=0; j<y; j+=width) // jump in block width through a row
              {
              sum = 0.0;

              for (int w=0; w<width; w++) // calculate average of a block
               {
                 sum += img[i][j+w] / width;
               }

            for (int b=0; b<width; b++) // write average in each pixel inside block
                {
                 result[i][j+b]= sum;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: No its not a 2D block. I just want the average of 4-16 Pixels in a row. So I get the average of, lets say 4 pixels, write it into a new matrix or overwrite the old 4 pixels and go to the next 4 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
//di means diagonal index
for(int di = 0; di < n/width; ++di) {

    int sum = 0.0;

    //we sum the values
    for(int i = di*width; i < (di+1)*width; ++i)                 
    {     
        for(int j = di*width; j < (di+1)*width; ++j)  
        {
            sum += Data[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Divide by the number of values
    sum /= width*width;

    //Spread the results
    for(int i = di*width; i < (di+1)*width; ++i)                 
    {     
        for(int j = di*width; j < (di+1)*width; ++j)  
        {
            IV_Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

//n might not be a multiple of width

if(n % width != 0) {
    //we sum the values
    for(int i = (n/width)*width; i < n; ++i)                 
    {     
        for(int j = di*width; j < (di+1)*width; ++j)  
        {
            sum += Data[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Divide by the number of values
    sum /= width*width;

    //Spread the results
    for(int i = (n/width)*width; i < n; ++i)                 
    {     
        for(int j = (n/width)*width; j < n; ++j)  
            IV_Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```